# How to retrieve multiple maximum values from a dictionary along with the keys

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I retrieve the maximum value of a dictionary along with its corresponding keys?

```
my_dict = {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 3}
maxValue = []
maximum = 0

for key, value in my_dict.items():
     if value >= maximum:
        maxValue.append(value)


number = max(maxValue)

print(number)
```

I've only been able to get the maximum value and the result is 5 which is expected however I can't seem to also retrieve the keys in which the max values correspond to. In this case the corresponding keys should be 2 and 4.

Comment: You will need 2 lists for that

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
my_dict = {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 3}

max_number=max(my_dict.values())

d=dict((key,value) for key, value in my_dict.items() if value == max_number)

print(d)
```

This will output as:

> {2: 5, 4: 5}

And if you only want to retrieve keys then you can do-

```
l=list(key for key, value in my_dict.items() if value == max_number)
print(l)
```

This will give as-

> [2, 4]

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dict of lists of keys indexed by the values in `my_dict`, so that you can map the max value to its corresponding list of keys:

```
d = {}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    d.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
print(d[max(d)])
```

This outputs:

```
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `operator.itemgetter` for that:

```
import operator
my_dict = {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 3}

key_max =  max(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
key_min =  min(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
print key_max, key_min
```

**output**

```
2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this like that:

```
my_dict = {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 3}
maxValue = -1
maxValueIndex = -1

for key, value in my_dict.items():
     if value >= maxValue:
        maxValue = value
        maxValueIndex = key

number = my_dict[key]

print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

my_dict = {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 3}

c = Counter(my_dict)

c.most_common(2)
# [(2, 5), (4, 5)]

[i for i, _ in c.most_common(2)]
# [2, 4]
```